# How can I transform 3-column pandas dataframe to matrix format in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix

I have 3 columns in my data-frame, namely X, Y, Z. I want to transform Z into a matrix based on X, Y (all columns having numerical values). X and Y have duplicate entries, hence a pivot table doesn't work. 
My code (n = #rows) :

```
mat = numpy.zeros((n, n))
for i in range (0, n):
   for j in range (0, n):
        if (Y[j] == Y[i]):
            mat[i, j] = Z[j]
        if (X[j] == X[i]):
            mat[i, j] = Z[i]
```

yields

```
[[6 10  0 0]
 [6 10 10 0]
 [0 10 10 0]
 [0  0  0 6]]
```

Data looks like:

```
X = array([100, 10, 10, 50]); 
Y = array([20, 20, 40, 60]); 
Z = array([6, 10, 10, 6]);
```

So the correct matrix should be:

```
[[6 10 10 0]
 [6 10 10 0]
 [0 10 10 0]
 [0  0  0 6]]
```

which is obtained by:

```
   | 100  10  10  50
--------------------
20 | 6   10  10   0
--------------------
20 | 6   10  10   0
--------------------
40 | 0   10  10   0
--------------------
60 | 0    0   0   6
--------------------
```

Comment: X forms the horizontal axis and Y forms the vertical axis.

Comment: Can you please explain, which problem you want to solve? I understand that your code sample does not generate the wanted result. However, you do not explain how the "correct matrix" has been created.

Comment: The correct matrix is created manually from the dataframe (columns X, Y, Z). For example, (100, 20) corresponds to 6, (10, 20) corresponds to 10 etc. so on for other elements of the matrix.

Comment: I am sorry, this is not enough explanation. "(100, 20) corresponds to 6" - I assume this is because Z[0] equals to 6. What follows is the mapping (100,20) -> 6; (10,20) -> 10; (10,40) -> 10 and (50, 60) -> 6. How does the "correct matrix" correspond to that? Why are some values 0?

Comment: You can now see how the above matrix has been constructed. For example, there's no mapping of (50, 40) in the dataframe (X, Y), hence Z = 0 for it.

Comment: That should help a lot. Thank's.

Comment: What if there is a duplicate entry. say X=[5,6,7,5]; Y=[1,2,3,1]; Z=[1,2,3,4]. The combination (5,1) could now be mapped to 1 or 4.

Comment: Duplicate entry for (X, Y) both will not be considered in the data. They will be removed first hand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When the proposed solution works for you, please klick on "accept answer" on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently don't see how to do this faster than with two for-loop. This should work:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': np.array([100, 10, 10, 50]),
    'Y': np.array([20, 20, 40, 60]),
    'Z': np.array([6, 10, 10, 6])
})

mapping = {(x, y): z for (x, y, z) in data[["X", "Y", "Z"]].values}

n = len(data)
mat = np.zeros((n, n))

for i, x in np.ndenumerate(data["X"]):
    for j, y in np.ndenumerate(data["Y"]):
        mat[j, i] = mapping.get((x, y), 0)

print(mat)
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 6. 10. 10.  0.]
 [ 6. 10. 10.  0.]
 [ 0. 10. 10.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  6.]]
```

I am creating a `mapping` that corresponds to the assignment of *(x, y) ⟶ z*.

With this is in place, filling the result matrix `mat` is pretty straight-forward.

Note however, that if there exist multiple columns with the same values for both `x` and `y`, the corresponding `z` value of the last column would be taken.